# Как исправить ошибку Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00000006 в zad1var.exe: 0xC00001A5

Tags: c++

В 16 рядке выдает ошибку: **Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00000006 в zad1var.exe: 0xC00001A5: Обнаружен недопустимый обработчик исключений (параметры: 0x00000003).**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int D[6][6];
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "a:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++)
        {D[i][j] = rand() % (b - a) + a;
            cout << D[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int max = D[0][0];
    int sumND = 1;
    int maxI = 0, maxJ = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (i + j == 5 ) sumND += D[i][j];
            if (D[i][j] > max)
            {
                maxI = i;
                maxJ = j;
                max = D[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "max=D[" << maxI << "]["<< maxJ<<"]="<< max << endl;
    cout << "Сума на допомiжнiй дiагоналi" << sumND;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++) - нестареющая классика опечаток или копипаста.

Comment: @gbg можете написать как правильно нужно написать

Comment: Я-то могу, но неужели вы не хотите научиться?

Comment: @gbg Я понял я вместо j i написал, спасибо